# Error compilando .ipa

Tags: ios

Buenos dias desde hace unos dias he tenido un error para compila un aplicativo para iOS en la plataforma lowcode Outsystems
me sale este error en los log de error (es un **.framework**)

```
[2021-01-12T22:17:12.411Z] [VERBOSE] [Build] error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:
[2021-01-12T22:17:12.411Z] [VERBOSE] [Build] 1) Target 'Sandbox PE APP' (project 'Sandbox PE APP'): CodeSign Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData....
[2021-01-12T22:17:12.412Z] [VERBOSE] [Build] 2) Target 'Sandbox PE APP' (project 'Sandbox PE APP'): CodeSign Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData...
```

y mas abajo vuelve a salir Unexpected duplicate tasks nuevamente

```
[2021-01-12T22:17:12.412Z] [VERBOSE] [Build] error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:
[2021-01-12T22:17:12.412Z] [VERBOSE] [Build] 1) Target 'Sandbox PE APP' (project 'Sandbox PE APP') has copy command from '/var/lib/builder01/builds/4b01a1f7-1648-47e2-9643-0f5b80d588ee/source...
[2021-01-12T22:17:12.412Z] [VERBOSE] [Build] 2) Target 'Sandbox PE APP' (project 'Sandbox PE APP') has copy command from '/var/lib/builder01/builds/4b01a1f7-1648-47e2-9643-0f5b80d588ee/source...
```

lo que creo que esta pasando es que estas tareas duplicadas están causando el error al compilar, pero no estoy seguro de como es que se da este tipo de errores

Saludos

Comment: Estás ejecutando la app desde Xcode?

Comment: no, se compila desde la plataforma lowcode y se ejecuta en los dispositivos fisicos